# How to check variable have a digit at the end or not

Tags: php

I have 2 variable 
**1 my file name**
 and 
**1 my file name 12**
.I want to check wheter there have a digit at the end or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$test="1 my file name 12";
$te = preg_match_all("/.*?(\d+)$/", $test, $digit);

if($te>0) {
    echo $test." have following digit in end".$digit[count($digit)-1][0];
}
```

**Result:** `1 my file name 12 have following digit in end 12`

Answer (score 0):

See the simple regex below:

```
$var = 'my file name 2';

if (preg_match('~\d$~', $var)) {
    echo 'second filename ends with a digit';
}
```